# Effect of deep-sea pressures on whales vs humans -- how do whales survive?

Tags: pressure, water, biophysics

I believe that humans would be crushed by the ocean at depths that whales regularly dive to. I know that the pressure per square inch is very high but whales can survive, I read, because of various adaptations.

But why would their flesh not be damaged by pressures even if the pressure was equal on all sides? What about flesh that is being pressed against the skeleton?

EDIT: I have of course googled this and know about adaptions that whales, etc. have as already mentioned but what I don't get is how a piece of flesh subjected to great pressures, like a car per square inch or whatever it is at a mile underwater, is not damaged -- how individual cells are not ruptured.

Comment: Perhaps this fits better in Biology SE

Comment: I think this is a physics question.

Comment: *"What about flesh that is being pressed against the skeleton?"* Do you feel crushed by the 14.7 pounds of air pressure on every square inch of your body? (I normally use metric, I only used psi in this comment because you mentioned square inches). FWIW, I think your question is ok here, but you may get more in-depth answers (pun intended) from the biologists.

Comment: @PM2Ring: apparently flesh can withstand that psi -- the question is how it can withstand many times that.

Comment: Did you at least try to google it? https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-do-deep-diving-sea-cr/

Comment: What do you mean by 'crushed' ? In fact it is really hard to crush any incompressible thing when applying a hydrostatic pressure (ie same pressure everywhere).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about biology not physics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the pressure of atmosphere doesn't crush you when you e.g. walk outside?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23866)

Comment: @PM2Ring “in-depth” answer: good pun.!

Comment: @sammygerbil I disagree that this question isn't about physics. Thinking about how biological tissue handles mechanical forces is certainly a biophysics question.

Comment: @AaronStevens It is debatable I think. To me question seems to be about comparative biology, a description of how whales are better adapted anatomically. The biophysics tag requires that the question be mainly about physics. This question would certainly be *on topic* at Biology SE. It would not be closed and sent back here.

Comment: @sammygerbil I think asking how a material can withstand forces is mainly about physics. Oh well

Comment: @AaronStevens That aspect is dealt with in the linked question. As far as I understand this problem is the same for whales as for humans. Unfortunately the title and the Edit ask different questions.